# Should i load image from server or fetch from url?

Tags: html, image

I am kind of new in web development, I wanted to create a Vuejs app of dota 2, there will be a grid of cards, in each card will be hero profile, I have all these heroes data locally in a json file with img path include, problem us there are so many images about 100 heroes and each have 4 ability so 100 hero avatar + 400 abilities it's kind of huge. Should I deploy these images to my hosting server or change img path to fetch from dota2.com ? Which is better and faster ? What effect on client side? My problem is I don't know if the client load images on the go or they need to download all 500 images first for my website to work.

If I am using url fetch, it mean my website is static or dynamic? Can I publish it to GitHub or need Firebase to hosting it?

Comment: This question is extremely broad. In short you should not directly serve images off of another server without permission as that is stealing their bandwidth.

Comment: But valve have an API for it and it's free, i dont want to use api because i wanted my website to be static

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing (hah, get it?) your situation, but right now [native lazy loading](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr) doesn't have good support, so I would go for asynchronous loading via JavaScript, using [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) + onload (there are many articles online) and possibly [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to load them when needed. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Static or dynamic refers to whether the data is constant or changes given a set of conditions. It seems that you have a list of images based on a field of Valve's API result set. I would suggest using those images for at least the following reasons:

1. A site as popular as valved more likely has caching across multiple regions. This means that if you are in Montana and the user is in Thailand there might be a copy of the image in a server closer to them than your single server; unless you also implement something similar of course.
2. You will not have to pay for the bandwidth which you are potentially authorized to use given you are using their API and they are given you a specific URL. You should read their terms and conditions.
3. If the image of the character changes it will update accordingly.
4. it is possible to serve multiple versions of the images based on the device. For instance a different image may be served for a mobile device than a desktop computer.

Note that the 3rd reason could be though of as being dynamic but it is not on your side. It is static in the sense that you will always use the image retrieved from the API. Also, consider the negative side effect of your json file if Valve changes an image. You should consider recreating the json file every so often.

The client side will be the same either way - a request will be issued for each image to either your server or the Valve server. The speed at which the image is served will be the determining factor.